# Mistake in (french) wikipedia on definition of limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definition

In the [french wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limite_(math%C3%A9matiques)#Limite_finie) they say that (for $f:U\to \mathbb R$ where $U$ open) that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)= \ell$ (where $a\in U$) if $$\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \delta >0: \forall x\in U, |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon .$$
Isn't it wrong ? For example, take $\displaystyle f(x)=\boldsymbol 1_{\{0\}}(x)$. Then, $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$, but according to the french wikipedia definition, it doesn't converges to $0$ since if $\varepsilon <1$, if $\delta >0$, then for $x=0$, we have that $|x-0|<\delta $, but $|f(x)-0|=1>\varepsilon $. Is this a mistakes or is it a more general definition that is more restrictive ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not wrong. Some authors use that definition of limit, with respect to which the value of $f$ at $a$ matters. You can recover the usual definition of limit from this one using the expression $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a,\ x\neq a}f(x)$.

Of course, under this definition, whenever $a$ belongs to the domain of $a$, the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ either doesn't exist or it is equal to $f(a)$.

Comment: Right. See the paragraph that I've added to my answer. A good reason for this definition is that it is a ittle strange that, as far as the limit of $f(x)$ at $a$ matters, knowing $f(x)$ when is is very close to $a$ is important, but when $x$ is actually *equal* to $a$ doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @John what they call the "limite épointée" in that page.

Comment: I see thank you. So at the end, only continuous function has a limit at $a$. But at the end, I've never heard about such a distinction, but now I see. @HennoBrandsma

Comment: Just one very last question. Without any precision, when we write $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$, we of course talk about the "epointé limit" right ? Otherwise, it wouldn't make a lot of sense, at least if $a$ is in the domain, right ?

Comment: It depends upon the context. It means the limit in the sense that the author of the text defined what limit is.